# Agilefant wont start

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu

I think I've problem with tomcat on my server.

Server os is Ubuntu server.

I can get inside to the tomcat and have uploaded the war file to tomcat. When I press start nothing happen. It doesn't show any warning or anything.

Check this image (screenshot from tomcat manager) http://jj.gd9.fi/matsku/agi.jpg

Any idea how to make it start?

Comment: Look at the logs, there is absolutely no information in what you posted except "doesn't start"